# issues when using ggsave to save the generated file into PDF

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use ggsave to save the figure generated using ggplot2, this is how I do

```
figure1<-last_plot()
ggsave(figure1,file="/home/user1/figure1.png",width=15,height=3)
```

These two lines of code successfully save the figure as png file.

However, when I tried to save it as pdf file,

```
 ggsave(figure1,file="/home/user1/figure1.pdf",width=15,height=36)
```

The saved pdf file is just a blank page. What's the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you have `height=3` in the `.png` and `height=36` in the `pdf`. Does swapping them change anything?

Comment: That code should work. Do you have a pdf driver installed? Does `pdf('mypdf.pdf'); plot(1,1); dev.off()` work?

Comment: Joh, yes, pdf('mypdf.pdf'); plot(1,1); dev.off() work  but use ggsave to generate pdf does not work

Comment: I have the same problem trying to save maps to pdf with ggsave(). Works fine with .png. Curiously, the pdf file visually appears blank, but the file is several MB in size. Basic plots like the mtcars example below work fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=hp))+
  geom_point()

figure1<-last_plot()
ggsave(figure1,file="figure1.png",width=15,height=3)
ggsave(figure1,file="figure1.pdf",width=15,height=3)

# works with R 2.15
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to save it using pdf() command:

```
library(ggplot2) 
pdf(file="figure.pdf",width=15,height=3)
figure <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=hp)) + geom_point()
print(figure)
dev.off()
```

I supose that it also doesn't work.

Solution (workaround) that should work is:

1) save it to svg file

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=hp)) + geom_point()
ggsave("figure.svg")
```

2) then convert it to pdf. E.g. in Linux

```
rsvg-convert -f pdf -o figure.pdf figure.svg
```

Comment: Please only answer the question when you are providing an answer, otherwise just leave a comment